# I can't create an object <__ main __. ClassNmae object at ...>

Tags: python

```
class Mylist(object): 
    def __init__(self):
        self.vals = []
        
    def insert(self, x):
        self.vals.append(x)
        
list1 = Mylist()
list1.insert(9)
list1.insert(8)
list1.insert(9)

print(list1)
```

Comment: You need to implement the function `__str__`

Comment: You can try something like this
`def __str__(self):   return ','.join(str(x) for x in self.vals)`